# WHy is it that in bootstrap when I minimize my window my <p> keeps getting longer and pushes all the content below it down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so I have a basic bootstrap layout

```
<div classs="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" style="background:black; padding:25px 0px;">content content</div>
</div>
<div class="span4 offset2">
    <p>blah blah blah this is a test blah blah blah this is a testblah blah blah this is a test <br />
       blah blah blah this is a testblah blah blah this is a testblah blah blah this is a test</p>
</div>
<div class="span12" style="blue; padding:25px 0px;">content content</div>
```

as I minimize the window the `<p>` will shrink in width but it will extend the paragraph down so it gets thinner and longer as the window minimizes it pushes ALL the content like the `span12` at the bottom down. I want the `<p>` to NOT get longer as the window minimizes but maybe smaller or something. I tried removing the margin and padding from it but when I do that it will keep the content in the bottom of the `<p>` from being pushed down but the `<p>` literally still extends under the bottom `span12` and creates a margin all the way at the bottom of the page. Can anyone tell me whats going on please.

**UPDATE:**

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lucaz5520/ZTgGX/ if you look at the paragraph as you minimize the window it will get thinner and push all the content below it down

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Have a look at the bootstrap stylesheet..

Comment: i bet you are using a `bootstrap-responsive.min.css`, it shrinks until the size of phone, and there it comes to block-mode to let the content adapt for the smartphones.

Comment: Assuming `span="row-fluid"` was supposed to be a `class=` declaration, and there should be spaces between  the class and style attributes, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vVveb/

Comment: Pretty sure you need to declare a new row-fluid for each span set: http://jsfiddle.net/chBHX/

Comment: Ok I have edited my mistakes when I was typing re-look at the question and no I am not using bootstrap-responsive.min.css .. ill try to make a fiddle hold on

Comment: Ok here is my fiddle as you minimize the window all the way the paragraph stretches out and pushes all the content DOWN. http://jsfiddle.net/Lucaz5520/CrqqF/

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is my fiddle as you minimize the window all the way the paragraph stretches out and pushes all the content DOWN.

```
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/CrqqF/
```

this damn thing isn't posting correctly it says I need to accompany my link with "code" and I did but it wont let me post. anyways just copy down that link

**my question will also be updated**